# Unity - Exporting to xcode Error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

i am getting an error while build and exporting to Xcode, the error is as follows

The file "project.xcworkspace" doesn't exist.

thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

it happens sometimes , you have to reBuild from unity project

Comment: it is not the answer to the question rather than a comment.